# Force child class to initialize fields

Tags: c#, oop

I have abstract base class that contains some fields and some methods that act on these fields. For example:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected double _field;

    public double SquaredField { get { return _field * _field; } }

    ... some other abstract methods
}
```

I want to impose that all children of A initialize _field in their constructors

```
public class B : A
{
    public B(double field)
    {
         _field = Math.Sqrt(field);
    }

    ... some other method implementations
}
```

What's the correct pattern to achieve this?

**-- EDIT**

What I ended up doing is:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected readonly double _field;

    public A(double field)
    {
         _field = field;
    }

    public double SquaredField { get { return _field * _field; } }

    ... some other abstract methods
}


public class B : A
{
    public B(double field) : base(field)
    {
    }

    public static B CreateNew(double val)
    {
         return new B(Math.Sqrt(field));
    }

    ... some other method implementations
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't expose a *field* to the derived classes at all. Instead, create a protected abstract *property*:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected double Field { get; }

    public double SquaredField { get { return Field * Field; } }
}
```

Or, if the field should always be constant for a particular instance, make it a constructor parameter and keep it private:

```
public abstract class A
{
    private readonly double _field;

    public double SquaredField { get { return _field * _field; } }

    protected A(double field)
    {
        _field = field;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I was starting to do your first choice, I was just wondering if it was the best way. In some ways, it doesn't force the children class to initialize anything, but at least it makes the developers of the child class think that the property needs to return something that's already initialized.

Comment: @d--b: It's hard to give more concrete advice without knowing the context. Personally I'm a big fan of immutability, which would make me lean towards the second option.

Comment: Mmmh, you're right. I am going to think about the whole design. I am probably not doing things properly in the first place...

Comment: In fact, you were right, I have chosen your second method. I think I got confused by the code that was a bit complex, but it clearly seems the right way to do it. See edit.

Comment: You can also make the setter PRIVATE and the getter public.  That will only allow the parent class to set the property.

Answer (score 3):

Don't let class `A` have a parameterless constructor:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected double _field;

    public double SquaredField { get { return _field * _field; } }

    // Require any fields that must be initialized in the base class's
    // constructor. If there are a lot of such fields, consider encapsulating
    // them all in their own class, e.g. AArgs.
    protected A(double field)
    {
        _field = field;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    // You must call a base class constructor as below, because class A
    // no longer has a parameterless constructor to use by default.
    public B(double field)
        : base(field)
    {
    }
}
```

#### Addendum

If you can't do the initialization in the constructor, you could make the field into an abstract property:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected abstract double Field { get; }

    public double SquaredField { get { return Field * Field; } }
}
```

Now, the derived class has to implement the property, so you'll have it ready for the dependent `SquaredField` property. I would change the name though, since they're not fields anymore.

Comment: I need to do some stuff in the constructor before calling the base constructor, so I can't use the base() constructor for that

Comment: Create a static factory method in the base class and abstract Init(...) method. Call Init() from the factory method. Make construtor protected. This will impose that children must implement initialization inside the Init().

Answer (score 2):

That's likely a signal that group of fields is more tightly coupled than `A` itself, and so should be moved to a class, say, `AParams`.

Then in `A` you can declare an `abstract protected AParams createParams()` method.

Comment: I think that's right. That goes along with the immutability argument

Comment: I don't buy this - quite often it's entirely valid to simply have constructors which force particular values to be provided by the subclass. Identifiers are pretty common in this scenario, for example. Note that we don't have a "group of fields" here - just a single field.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, 'contains some fields' and 'I need to do some stuff in the constructor before calling the base constructor, so I can't use the base() constructor for that'. You don't have to buy it, still %) I'd go with constructor myself if C# implementation wasn't against this particular case %)

Comment: @VictorSergienko: True, I'd missed that in the question - and I hadn't read comments on other answers :) Basically it's the kind of situation where we'd really need to have a lot more context to be able to give more concrete guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate abstract function to accomplish this. The subclasses would be forced to implement it.

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected double _field;

    protected A()
    {
        InitializeField();
    }

    protected abstract void InitializeField();

    public double SquaredField { get { return _field * _field; } }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void InitializeField()
    {
        // Initialize...
    }
}
```